# WIX: Can i define a property based on another property in WIX?

Tags: wix

Can i do something like this?

```
    <?if ISTEST="0"?>
    <?define SkyLibFolder = "Prod"?>
    <?else ?>
    <?define SkyLibFolder = "Test"?>
    <?endif ?>
```

I need to have a variable FolderPath which is then used later in the WIX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a type 51 custom action to set the property, you should make use of the [SetProperty Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/setproperty.html).

```
<SetProperty Action="SetSkyLibFolderA" Id="SkyLibFolder" Before="InstallFiles" Value="Prod"><![CDATA[ISTEST=0]]></SetProperty>
<SetProperty Action="SetSkyLibFolderB" Id="SkyLibFolder" Before="InstallFiles" Value="Test"><![CDATA[ISTEST=1]]></SetProperty>
```

Inner Text (xs:string)
The condition that determines whether the Property is set. If the condition evaluates to false, the Set is skipped.

Edit: [Type 51 Custom Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368237%28VS.85%29.aspx) sets a property from a formatted text string. In simple terms, Type 51 custom actions are basically just assignment statements (abc="xyz") ***at setup time***. For example, consider you want to change the install location based on a registry entry on the target machine.We need the assignment statement as the install location is not known until we start the installation.

```
<!-- Find install path from registry -->
<Property Id="XYZFOLDER">
  <RegistrySearch Id="XyzRegistry"
                  Root="HKLM"
                  Key="SOFTWARE\MyXYZ\XyzProduct"
                  Name="InstallDir"
                  Type="raw" />
</Property>

<!-- Set the property -->
<CustomAction Id="SetXYZLocation"
              Property="XyzLocation"
              Value="[XYZFOLDER]xyz.exe" />
```

Now the CustomAction (SetXYZLocation) should be scheduled properly within the InstallExecuteSequence.

With the SetProperty element, the custom action and the scheduling of the custom action is taken care by the Wix code internally.

Comment: Do I need to implement the Action -> SetSkyLibFolderA, SetSkyLibFolderB?

Comment: Also what do we mean by type 51 custom action?

Comment: "My intention is to have this property on which I can determine the Installation path of the DLLs. I have the installation of test version of dlls based on the parameter ISTEST = 1, or by default its 0." - I don't think this is the right approach, you MSI/Package should always mimic the production environment. So I think your DLL's should go to the same location regardless of test vs prod otherwise there can be unforeseen issues.

Comment: The reason is to install - basically gac and register the test versions based on the Switch statement. Can't i do that?

Comment: From the limited information that I have above my point is there shouldn't be a difference between your prod MSI vs test MSI. They should be deploying files to the same folder etc, otherwise your testing is not really complete.

Comment: Thanks @Isaiah4110. I do want to put the test and prod binaries to same folder but I am getting an error saying that I can't have 2 components having same keypath.

Comment: What's the difference between your test and prod binaries?

Comment: I think I got it. The difference is the dlls that they need to place in the drop folder and gac the prod/test versions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for WiX preprocessor variables. 
Yes, for Windows Installer properties.

It's not clear which you should use.

A WiX Product setup produces Windows Installer packages (MSI). Other than providing a few custom actions (a type of Windows Installer extension) that you might choose to use, WiX is not involved in the actual installation. So, if you want something that changes at install-time, you have to use a Windows Installer construct.

Comment: Thanks Tom. My intention is to have this property on which I can determine the Installation path of the DLLs. I have the installation of test version of dlls based on the parameter ISTEST = 1, or by default its 0. I am getting confused on how do i achieve it

Comment: Do you want one MSI for both Test and Prod installations? Or, do you one WiX project to build either a Test MSI or a Prod MSI?

Comment: I want one MSI for both Test and Prod installations.

Comment: Then @Issiah4110's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24544632/2226988) is what you want.